# Zend ACL throwing exception on non-existing resources

Tags: zend-framework2, acl

I'm trying to get Zend ACL up and running but I seem to be running into the following problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Permissions\Acl\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Resource 'article-2' not found' in vendor/zendframework/zend-permissions-acl/Zend/Permissions/Acl/Acl.php:292
```

I get the impression that Zend ACL throws and exception when a resource is not added to the resource list. To give an example:

```
$user1 = 'user-1';
$user2 = 'user-2';

$article1 = 'article-1';
$article2 = 'article-2';

$acl = new Acl();

$acl->addRole( new Role('user') );
$acl->addRole( new Role('user-1'), 'user' );
$acl->addRole( new Role('user-2'), 'user' );

$acl->addResource( $article1 );

$acl->allow( $user1, $article1 );

echo $acl->isAllowed( $user1, $article2 ) ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

As you can see, I'm creating 3 roles, one generic user role and two user specific roles. Then I create two articles and I allow user 1 to access article 1. But, when if I now test if user 1 can access article 2, BOOM, exception!

The `isAllowed' should obviously just return false instead of throwing an exception. Imagine I have 1000 users and 1000 articles, it would mean that besides specifying which users can access which article, I also need to specify which articles they cannot accessed by each user. This obviously results in ridiculous long ACL's and memory consumption, and to top it off, articles aren't my only type of resources!

Other that wrapping the `isAllowed` in a `try/catch` (which is obviously clunky), what would be the best way to cope with this odd behavior?

Comment: Looking into this deeper I now seem to understand why this is happening. The above example is a hard coded example, in a dynamic situation, the resource to test against will ALWAYS be added to the ACL resource list. This means that the above example which throws and exception is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if your commet means that you already are ok. 
Anyways, in this situations , before you check if something isAllowed, what you can do is just:

```
 if(!$acl ->hasResource($resource))
                $acl -> addResource(new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource($resource));
```

Or even take the time to **extend the default ACL** class, so the `isAllowed` method, first of all,  include the code above. That would be a simple [Poka-Yoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke) practice, and will allow you to maintain the original model where you have to create resources, while promoting ease of use in common or majority use cases.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. You are correct. I failed to understand why the exception was thrown but I later understood why that behavior is actually correct. The ACL needs a role and a resource. In a hard coded scenario such as my question they should both exist. In a dynamic scenario where you create your ACL on the fly you will always have both at your disposal. However, your subclass solution might provide a way to gracefully deal with this situation just in case...

Comment: yeah, it could be tricky to develop, but it is possible,  So if in the future you have a good picture of how your ACL should fulfill your business rules, and you can figure out how to automatize certain aspects, you can go for it and create your own child class.  Indeed i have my custom ACL that allows me to create rules such as access levels, directly in the router config, which is greatly convenient) and it is working like charm. If you go for it...get ready for some fun!